# Issue with summernote-rails and ActiveAdmin: all colors in color picker are grey

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sass, coffeescript, summernote

[Color picker in summer note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDwNf.png)

Hi,

Recently I implemented the gem summernote-rails in my app, and I am using it in ActiveAdmin to edit the `html_content` of a model `email`. Everything is functioning minus one thing: the colors in the colors picker views are all grey, but the colors are not grey.
Here I let you my files related with scss and coffee-script:

In app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.coffee

```
#= require active_admin/base
#= require bootstrap
#= require summernote

$ -> 
  $(".summernote").summernote()
```

In app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.scss

```
// Active Admin's got SASS!
@import "active_admin/mixins";  
@import "active_admin/base"; 
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome';
@import 'variables/colors';
@import 'summernote';
@import 'email';
```

In app/admin/email.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Email do
  permit_params :name, :title, :html_content

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Blog Post' do
    f.input :name
    f.input :title
    f.input :html_content, input_html: { class: 'summernote' }
  end
  f.actions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I finaly solve it with a colleague, the issue came from ActiveAdmin which overwrite `background-image`. So I proceed like that:

In app/assets/stylesheets/email.scss

```
.note-color-btn { 
  background-image: none; 
}
```